# Install pfctl on focal (20.04)

Tags: ssh, 20.04

I am using sshuttle with pf method, it's the only method working for my use case. Is there a way to have pfctl installed in Ubuntu focal 20.04?

Comment: AFAIK **pfctl** hasn't been ported to linux.But you can clone to the [OpenBSD](https://github.com/openbsd/src) repo and build it.There's gonna be a binary with the name ```pfctl``` in the [sbin/pfctl](https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/sbin/pfctl) directory after a successful compilation as it's clear from the [makefile](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sbin/pfctl/Makefile).But I hadn't done it myself yet.

Comment: And [BPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter) has been implemented in the linux kernel, and I think there shouldn't be any problem using pfctl on top of the linux kernel, but I haven't tried that just yet.BPF is now used in the linux kernel for various performance analysis tasks but since we have iptables , we don't use PF as the firewall :)